# How does var not in list and not var in list differ?

Tags: django-templates

What is the difference between doing:

```
{% if my_var not in my_list %}
  {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if not my_var in my_list %}
  {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

when `my_list` is None and `my_var` is `"1"` in templates? In the first case {{my_var}} doesn't get printed, but it does in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `my_list` isn't a container *at all*, both comparisons return false. The difference is that the second turns the false into a true and prints `my_var`.